# Is there a loop consisting of an odd number of moves for the Rubik's cube?

Tags: group-theory, rubiks-cube

I'm considering a loop to be a sequence of moves that brings a Rubik's cube configuration back to its original state. One example is if you turn any face a quarter turn four times, or if you turn one face a quarter turn and then reverse it. My question is, is there a loop that consists of an odd number of moves (considering a half turn to be two moves, obviously), and if there is, what is its minimum size?

Comment: To be clear, are you considering only R, R', L, L', U, U', F, F', D, D', and B, B'?  Or do you also allow M or E slices?

Comment: Yes, only the moves R, R', L, L', U, U', F, F', D, D' and B, B'. Sorry, should have pointed that out!

Comment: Assuming you only allow quarter turns of a single face at a time, this gets into the idea of even vs odd permutations.  The identity permutation is an even permutation.  You can show that a quarter turn is an odd permutation.  An odd number of odd permutations in sequence will again be odd, and thus not equal to any even permutation such as the identity.

Comment: @JMoravitz What would be an "M" and what an "E"-move ? I guess "M" stands for something as "middle" , but what about "E" ?

Comment: I guessed that the parity would forbid this , nice.

Comment: @Peter that is cubing terminology.  The M slice is the one which takes the layer between the left face and right face and moves that while keeping both the left and right faces stationary.  E is the same but the horizontal layer between top and bottom.  S is the layer between front and back (*unless I got E and S mixed up, I hardly ever use them*).  M's are very common in most techniques, especially as it comes to solving the last layer of a cube.  See [this](https://jperm.net/images/notation.png) for common notations.  Use a ' to indicate the reverse, or a 2 to indicate half turns.

Comment: The reason why I had to ask about M slices is because an M slice is actually equal to RL'x', (and it wasn't clear if you counted cube rotations as moves) so it could have been able to circumvent that.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, I had a feeling that the configurations had an even/odd parity structure, but I wasn't sure how to prove it. I guess that one could consider all possible configurations of, say, a single edge piece (24 configurations) and map the moves between them to show the full structure. Or is there an even more trivial way to show it?

Comment: Do you know some group theory? Or any facts about the permutation group $S_n$?

Comment: I mean... my first instinct would be to consider the rubiks group as a subgroup of $S_{54}$ (noting $54 = 6\times 9$) and looked at what the parity is of the R move is in that context.  (*we are ignoring orientations of stickers, such as on picture cubes and treating all stickers as being uniquely labeled*).  You'll see that it is equal to the product of five disjoint 4-cycles.  The parity of a permutation is odd if it's disjoint cyclic composition consists of an odd number of even-length cycles (*and any number of odd-length cycles*), hence R is odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recapping the comments:

One can view the rubik's group as a subgroup of $S_{54}$ and within the context of $S_{54}$ you can view a quarter turn of a face move as the composition of five length-4 cycles.

(*More specifically, using [blindfold notation](https://jperm.net/bld) of the stickers and capitals to indicate corners versus lowercase to indicate edges, you could view the move R as the permutation $(C~Q~W~K)(B~T~V~J)(M~N~O~P)(b~t~v~j)(m~n~o~p)$*)

It is well known that in the context of permutation groups you may refer to the [*parity* of the permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) (*the even-ness or the odd-ness*) and one of the results of such study is that if you were to express an even permutation (*such as the identity*) as the composition of several other permutations, the number of odd permutations appearing in such a composition must have been even and could not have been odd.  This is just like how in numbers, if you add an odd number of odd numbers together (*and any number of even numbers*) then the result will be odd and not even.

Further, it is known that a permutation is odd if and only if the number of even-length cycles in its disjoint cyclic decomposition is odd.  As such, the move R (*and indeed all other quarter-turn face moves*) are odd permutations.

It follows then that the answer to your question is that *no*, there do not exist any sequences of moves consisting only of quarter face turns that are of odd-length which are equivalent to the identity.

Comment: Thanks, this makes very much sense! I'm only just starting to learn group theory. It was actually in the studies, when we just briefly touched upon the Rubik's group, that got me to think about my question.

Comment: @emmm getting deeper into the nuances of the rubiks cube is actually tremendously helpful in getting tactile and visual examples of some of the topics discussed.  For an example, take a solved cube and repeat a simple algorithm like $RUR'U'$ (*the "sexy move"*).  You will find that enough applications of the same algorithm will eventually take you back to a solved state (*what you called a "loop"*) and the number of applications of the algorithm needed will always be some divisor of the order of the group, $2^{27}3^{14}5^37^211$ (*per Lagrange's Theorem*)

Comment: In practice, if you used a short simple algorithm like the sexy move, that might be short like $6$ applications, but also of interest is things like a devil's algorithm... an algorithm which simply cycles through all arrangements of the cube in sequence and will inevitably solve any cube (*so long as you can pay attention to when you are allowed to stop*) but will be horrendously slow to do so.  Commutators as well in group theory correspond directly with commutators in cubing theory and are a joy to get your hands on.